# onActiveChanged not working every time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a simple chrome extension with the following data but for some reason it is not working all the time, there are times which I need to click on the extension button for it to work next time in the current tab.
I am unable to understand why.. it should ALWAYS work when you click on a tab and activate it (even when you create a new tab - it become activated and should run `do-something.js`

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'do-something.js'
  });
});
```

do-something.js

```
function createNotification() {
  var notification = document.createElement('div');
  Object.assign(notification.style, {
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: 10000,
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    background: '#f5ae20',
    padding: '5px',
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });
  notification.innerHTML = `Test`;
  document.body.appendChild(notification);
  setTimeout(function() {
    notification.remove();
  }, 4000);
  return notification;
}
createNotification();
```

Why is it not working all the time?

Comment: Why don't you use "content_scripts"?  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ], 

and add a listener in content.js chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
after that send a message from background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some issue with your code. `do-something.js` should be mentioned in the manifest file otherwise chrome will not find anything, you can put is as *content script*, *background script* or *web accessible resource*.

But if you put it as content script than it will run every time when the page will load (according) to your current code.

Here is my approach
I put the `do-something.js` in content script and made a communication channel between background js and content script when in the background it finds that active tab has changed then send a message to content script and display the notification

message passing from background

```
//listener for detecting tab change
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(function () {
  console.log("tab changed");
  //query about the active tab and get the tab id
  //if you add debug point here it will throw exception because debugger is the current active window , which doesnot have tab
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    //send the message to the content sctipt
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "showNotification", null);//here null is the callback
  });
});
```

Message reception on content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    //you can receive  different type of message here
    if (message == "showNotification") {
      createNotification();
    }
  });
```

I have added a github repo for you, you can find more details there.
https://github.com/pfrng/tabChangeListener

Thanks